# warbler Gemfile path option not supported

Tags: jruby, warbler

Is there a recommended workaround for warbler not supporting the path options in a Gemfile?
Is there a fundamental reason why path is not supported (and I couldn't just implement it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path option is not portable. Bundler expects to be able to find the code at that path, which sort of defeats the purpose of a self-contained war file.

A workaround would be to run "git init; git commit -a" in the directory of the path-based gem and treat it like a git-based gem instead. Then Bundler can check out a copy of the code and Warbler can store the copy in the war file.

Comment: thanks. If the path directory is within my project, than it is portable, and there would be a way to add support to warbler right?

Answer (score 0):

I (unfortunately) can't post code for this (yet...), but I have successfully done the following:

1. Hack warbler (basically replace the whole bundler gem packaging code) to copy gems specified with `:path` into `vendor/gems` (normal gem location is `gems/gems`).  This copying was done nearly identically to how warbler copies gems from a `:git` specification.
2. Monkeypatch bundler so when it loads a `Gemfile` with `:path` specs, they are rewritten to point into `vendor/gems`.

It's not pretty, but I have been very happy with this solution.

---

Another option I have seen is to create a `vendor/gems` directory which contains symlinks to all the gems that use `:path` in the Gemfile.  Warbler will complain about not supporting `:path` gems, but they will be copied in the WAR file via the symlinks.  I do not like this solution because you've got to maintain the `:path` in the Gemfile and the symlink, but it is easier to implement than the above.

---

Also, I agree with Nick Siger that supporting `:path` as-is (without any of the above hacks) does defeat the purpose of a self-contained WAR file, but a self-contained WAR file is not always desirable.  There are tradeoffs to a not-self-contained WAR file of course, but one advantage is being smaller in size, quicker to copy, unzip, etc.  Of course, supporting this would require changes to JRuby-Rack as well as to Warbler.